# Why this api call not returning the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url  : 'http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/what-makes-us-happy/data/summary.csv',
  type : 'get',
  }).done(function(data, statusText, xhr){
  var status = xhr.status;                //200
  var head = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(); //Detail header info
   alert(data);
})
```

can anybody explain me why this api call not returning the data i want. is there any mistake i am doing? I have tried with plain get request too. What am doing wrong?

Comment: look at your browser console.. you should see something like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/what-makes-us-happy/data/summary.csv. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. `

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/what-makes-us-happy/data/summary.csv?_=1411025854415. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin  http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.

So it seems that CORS is not allowing you to get the data.